# XML Child Node count - Java

Tags: java, xml

I need to get the count of the number of child nodes underneath a parent tag `<test>` in the below example.

So count of `<username>`, `<password>` and `<result>` = 3.

```
<TestData>
    <test>
        <username>test1234</username>
        <password>fake</password>
        <result>Incorrect Login or Password</result>
    </test>
    <test>
        <username>abc</username>
        <password>1234</password>
        <result/>
    </test>
</TestData>
```

I have managed to get the count of `<test>` as follows;

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("test");
TEST_CASE_COUNT = nList.getLength();
```

Now I need the count of the child nodes within `<test>`

Comment: What would you expect the result to be if one of your `test` elements had 3 children and the other had 4?

Comment: That's two results, not one... hint: you need to clarify your requirements...

Comment: "..the count of the number of child nodes underneath a parent tag."  Is my terminology incorrect?  I just need to know how to get the child node count under a parent - specifically under <test> as in this example.  I'm sure the solution can then be applied to a scenario where there are x children, if needed.  many thanks

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that it was for one specific test element. In particular, you've found the number of test elements, but there can be different numbers of elements under each. It's hard to tell what you want the code to look like at the moment... What would a suitable method signature be, for example?

Comment: public static int GetTestParameterCount( NodeList nList ) ... if NodeList is what needs to be passed through to get the count !

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by that method signature - which NodeList would you pass in? The one containing the `test` elements, or one for *each* `test` element. It would really help if you'd show a short but complete console app demonstrating what you're trying to achieve, if my answer doesn't help you...

Comment: I am trying to copy the XML data into an Object[][]
so for example, the Object[0][1] would = fake.
I am probably doing this the totally wrong way...

Comment: Well that sounds like an entirely different question, and nothing to do with counts. (I'd suggest using lists instead, which makes life simpler.)

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of child *elements* within a particular element, you need to take account of the fact that not all *nodes* are elements. For example, you could use:

```
static int getChildElementCount(Element element) {
    int count = 0;
    NodeList childNodes = element.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        if (childNodes.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_TYPE) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

There may be a simpler way using XPath to select just elements, too. (I rarely find XPath a simpler solution, but YMMV.)

Comment: I don't know why this answer wasn't picked as the answer! It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `Node.getChildNodes()`. You would have to loop through your list of `<test>` and then count the children for each one, adding them as you go.

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("test"); 
int TEST_CASE_COUNT = nList.getLength();
int nodeCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node test = nList.item(i);
    nodeCount += test.getChildNodes().getLength();
}
```

Comment: This is returning 14 using the above code... Am I missing something?

Comment: I think Jon Skeet more or less explains why in his answer. Are you expecting to get back 3 though?